# Calculate simple expression: $\sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{5}} + \sqrt[3]{2 - \sqrt{5}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

Tell me please, how calculate this expression:

$$
\sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{5}} + \sqrt[3]{2 - \sqrt{5}}
$$

The result should be a number.

I try this:

$$
\frac{\left(\sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{5}} + \sqrt[3]{2 - \sqrt{5}}\right)\left(\sqrt[3]{\left(2 + \sqrt{5}\right)^2} - \sqrt[3]{\left(2 + \sqrt{5}\right)\left(2 - \sqrt{5}\right)} + \sqrt[3]{\left(2 - \sqrt{5}\right)^2}\right)}{\left(\sqrt[3]{\left(2 + \sqrt{5}\right)^2} - \sqrt[3]{\left(2 + \sqrt{5}\right)\left(2 - \sqrt{5}\right)} + \sqrt[3]{\left(2 - \sqrt{5}\right)^2}\right)} =
$$

$$
= \frac{2 + \sqrt{5} + 2 - \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt[3]{\left(2 + \sqrt{5}\right)^2} + 1 + \sqrt[3]{\left(2 - \sqrt{5}\right)^2}}
$$

what next?

Comment: That made me laugh: "the result should be a number". What else? :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $s=a+b$ be our sum, where $a=\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{5}}$. Note that
$$s^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)=a^3+b^3+3abs.$$
Thus since $a^3+b^3=4$ and $ab=\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$, we have
$s^3=4-3s$. This has the obvious root $s=1$ and no other real root.

Comment: It might help to see the roots to note that $s^3+3s-4=(s^2+4)(s-1)$.

Comment: @robjohn Actually, it is $s^3+3s-4 = (s-1)(s^2+s+4)$.

Answer (score 3):

Would it help you to know that

${2\pm\sqrt5}=\left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}2\right)^3$  ?

Comment: More simple, but not obvious solution. Thank you for callback.

Answer (score 1):

$(\sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{5}} + \sqrt[3]{2 - \sqrt{5}} )^3 \\
=(\sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{5}})^3+(\sqrt[3]{2 - \sqrt{5}} )^3+3(\sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{5}} ) (\sqrt[3]{2 - \sqrt{5}} )(\sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{5}} +\sqrt[3]{2 - \sqrt{5}} )   $

S0 $s^3=4-3s$ From this we get S = 1

Answer (score 0):

, Let $$x = \sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{5}}\;,$$ Then we can write as $$\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}}+(-x) = 0$$

Now Using If $$\bullet \; a+b+c = 0\;,$$ Then $$a^3+b^3+c^3 = 3abc$$

So $$\left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)+\left(2-\sqrt{5}\right)-x^3 = 3\left[\sqrt[3]{\left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)\cdot \left(2-\sqrt{5}\right)}\right]\cdot (-x)$$

So $$4-x^3 = -3x\Rightarrow x^3+3x-4=0\Rightarrow (x-1)\cdot (x^2+x+4)=0$$

So we get $$x=1\Rightarrow \sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{5}} = 1$$

Comment: Another interesting solution. I noticed one little mistake. Instead $(x-1)\cdot (x^2 + 4)=0$ must be $(x-1)\cdot (x^2+ x + 4)=0$. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Yura, I have edited it.