# Factoring an irrational number into a cube

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I have a math problem in which I need to calculate : $$\sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{5}} + \sqrt[3]{2 - \sqrt{5}}$$

In one of the previous problems in which there were steps to calcuate, they separated the numbers so they get a cube like $(a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3$,
where $a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3 = 2 + \sqrt{5}$ so that cube and cube root cancel each other.


I guessed many numbers and didn't get the right one. Also I was wondering if there was other way to solve this problem or easier way to complete cube without having to guess until you get the right numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate simple expression: $\sqrt[3]{2 + \sqrt{5}} + \sqrt[3]{2 - \sqrt{5}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416720/calculate-simple-expression-sqrt32-sqrt5-sqrt32-sqrt5) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B2%2B%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D%2B%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7B2-%5Csqrt%7B5%7D%7D%24&p=1). Note that this [answer](/a/1416727) , and this other [one](/a/1416748), there both use a similar technique to what you're suggesting, & what I used in my now deleted answer. ...

Comment: I don't know what kind of "guessing" you did. The number is handed to you as a sum of two numbers, that is, it's handed to you in the form $a+b$, now all you have to do is cube it. No guessing needed.

Comment: (cont.) In addition to the $2$ other questions that one was closed as a duplicate of, there are additional site duplicates, e.g., [Sum of two irrational numbers](/q/2523820). There are also several AoPS questions regarding this, e.g., [Cube root](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1314239p7052206), [How to find cube root](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1314239p7052206), etc. Last, but not least, welcome to Math SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi$ denote the golden ratio as the bigger root satisfying $\phi^2-\phi-1=0$. It is also denoted as $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$. Multiplying by $\phi$ and adding one: $$\phi^2-\phi-1=0\implies\phi^3-\phi^2-\phi=0\implies\phi^3=\phi^2+\phi=2\phi+1$$Note that $2\phi+1=2+\sqrt5$, therefore the first radicand is $\phi$. The second radicand can be proved to be the other root of $x^2-x-1=0$, which is the conjugate of $\phi$ very similarly. The sum of these two is just $1$ because the sum of two roots of a quadratic equation is the same as its leading coefficient, which is the answer.